# Executing SQL Query on Entity Framework derived class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using inheritance with Entity Framework model first. I have a base class EQUIPMENT, with derived classes such as EQUIPMENT_A. I would like to be able to write a SQL query that can get all EQUIPMENT_A tables and get the base properties in EQUIPMENT, but when I look at the EQUIPMENT_A table, there is no ParentID and seemingly know way to reference the parent except in code. How can I go about doing this? Thanks.

Also, I do not know what formatting people are having issues with and I apologize, as it seems to appear fine to me.

```
**BASE CLASS**
-- Creating table 'EQUIPMENTs'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EQUIPMENTs] (
[Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SNumber] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[BoxNumber] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
[DateReleased] datetime  NULL,
[NFES] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[IssuedDate] datetime  NULL,
[ItemDescription] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[ModulationType] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[Bandwidth] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
[IsSpecial] bit  NOT NULL,
[RepeaterUsed] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
[Technician] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
[ADM] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
[INCIDENT_Id] int  NULL,
[DESIGNATOR_Id] int  NULL,
[C_LINK_SELECTION_Id] int  NOT NULL
```

);

```
**THIS TABLE derives from EQUIPMENT**
-- Creating table 'EQUIPMENTs_EQUIPMENT_4312'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EQUIPMENTs_EQUIPMENT_4312] (
[Id] int  NOT NULL
```

);

Comment: Perhaps it may be a *shared primary key*.  In other words, the primary key in both tables is identical, and you can join on it.

Comment: can you show your models and your mapping classes? i can think of a couple reasons why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Also please improve the formatting of your question, it's hard to read like this.

Comment: _SQL query that can get all EQUIPMENT_A tables_ => are you sure you mean _tables_ and not _records_?

Comment: Sorry I meant records. 

AaronLS-How do I create a shared primary key with a derived type? I can't seem to set "Entity Key" on any property in the derived entity.

Comment: @John I was suggesting that it may already be setup like that by EF, not saying you would set that up.  In which cause you can just join on he primary keys.  I interpreted "except in code" to mean that you are trying to write a SQL query to accomplish this, not LINQ, correct?  It would be best to show the table structure, script the CREATE statement or something similar so we can see the table structure.

Comment: AaronLS- You are correct. It works in code using objects, but I was not sure how I would use this shared primary key if it exists, since when I look at the tables, there seems to be NO ID linking them together. I will post the table structure now. Thanks.